# Similar to at least one matrix whose elements on the diagonal are equal to zero.

Tags: linear-algebra

If the trace of the matrix A of order n above the field R is equal to zero, prove that it is similar to at least one matrix whose elements on the diagonal are equal to zero.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE Alex. Please shoe your work.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint: prof by induction on the dimension $n$ of the space**

If $n=1$ the result is trivial.

Suppose that the result is proven for matrices of size $n \times n$ and let’s suppose that $A$ is of dimension $(n+1)\times(n+1)$.

If $A$ is the matrix of an homothetic transformation of ratio $\lambda$ then $0=\operatorname{tr}(A)= (n+1)\lambda$. Therefore $\lambda =0$ and $A=0$, which proves the result. If $A$ is not the matrix of an homothetic transformation, it exists a vector $u$ such that $(u,A.u)$ is linearly independent. You can complete this family into a basis $(u,A.u, e_3, \dots,u_{n+1})$.

In this basis the matrix of $A$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \times & \dots & \times\\
1 & \\
0 &\\
\vdots && A^\prime\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $A^\prime$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with vanishing trace. You can apply the induction hypothesis to $A^\prime$ and conclude the proof from there.